# Python, Pygame Mouse events

Tags: python, pygame

How would I assign the variables x, y to the x and y position, respectivly, of a the mouse pointer when it is pressed down (clicked).

Heres what I have thus far:

```
from pygame import*
init()
SIZE = (width, height)
screen = display.set_mode(SIZE)
position = 0
Running = True
while Running:
    for evnt in event.get():
         if evnt.type == QUIT:
             Running = False 
         elif evnt.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
             position = evnt.pos
```

Currently, position is in the form (x position, y position). 
How would I access the individual elements?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`position` is a `tuple` so you can

```
position = evnt.pos
x = position[0]
y = position[1]
```

or

```
x, y = position
```

or even

```
x, y = evnt.pos
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not used pygame in a while nor do i still have it so i can't test this code but I'm pretty sure its correct. first you test if the mouses left button is clicked

The get_pressed function returns three values for each button on a mouse i may be wrong thinking the first value returned is the value for mouse button one.

If the mouse is clicked, we proceed to get the mouses coords and store them.

```
if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]
    cord = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
```

Also, from what i understand pygame does not use a z value as the library is only a 2D library so this gives you a X, Y value.

Comment: this is not correct - get_pressed gives you a tuple like (1,0,0) meaning button one is pressed so it won't give you coordinates check this out here: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html